# Delete an item in an Accordion

Tags: accordion

Just wondering where the most conventional location for a delete button on an Accordion item should be?

Are there just 2 valid options? And which one is more conventional?

**1. On the Item:** [item    x →] (either individually or in a multi select way with a tools like Google Inbox email items)

**2. Inside the Item:**

[item    ↓

delete]

Thanks!

Comment: It is not often that I see people wanting to delete inside an accordion, mainly because they are generally used for menu items, whereas tables are traditionally where data rather than navigational elements are grouped. Can you provide more details so people might understand the context better? It will also help to give you better answers from the community.

Comment: Although I agree with @DaveAlger if you MUST use an accordion, I second Michael's comment that accordion usually are navigation elements. Why do you want data (that may need to be deleted) into an accordion?

Comment: Hey thanks for the info so far. Yeah sure. It was already existing and I can't change it unfortunately but need to add the delete functionality. It's a list of Favorite Items which you add a comment about it. All the items are listed and when you expand the accordion you see the comment. You can also edit the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option 1 is better:  `[item -> delete]`

In a vertical list of items delete works best directly to the right of the item being removed.  This is because our eyes scan the page from top to bottom and left to right in the shape of a letter F.  By the time we get to the bottom of an accordion item the context of what would be deleted is lost.

This is further compounded by the fact that scrolling could have a possible floating delete button where the item title is no longer visible.

Comment: Yeah cool thanks, that's what I was leaning towards. Just like the Google Contacts UI which is a Row/Modal info rather than Row/Accordion info, and they have the delete on the row.